# Can maven open a vpn connection?

Tags: maven, vpn

I've got a maven project that creates a webService clients with WSDL2Java.
On development environment i've got direct accessto the urls to the WSDL, but for productive environments, i need to connect to an VPN to access to the WSDL url.

Can i create a VPN connection with maven to have access to those urls?

Thanks!

Comment: That sounds complicated. Why not establish the VPN outside of Maven and then just run the build normally?

Comment: The thing is that if i want to do so, i must send the code to a virtual machine, and the open the vpn and open the build. it's possible but its a little annoying as you can see.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using the [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) to launch the local tool of choice that opens your vpn connection.

But beware that this makes the build depend on your local environment so you should at least use a maven profile to add this step.

Comment: of course, i didn't tell so but, i use a profile for each environment ;)
I'll make a try! thanks a lot!! :)